# Confusion in testing part of Object Detection

Tags: image-processing, object-detection

I'm new to image processing and I want to do a project in object detection. I have started studying about the object detection from different papers. I have few confusion about the testing part.

**Training:**
We have different objects in the images so first, we will use our object proposal extraction method to extract the objects with the help of ground truth  and do training (car, airplane). Using ground truth just to increase the data size for the training. So we use the ground truth and match it with the extracted proposal. If the matching ratio is above 0.5 then we can take that extracted proposal for the training set.

**Testing**
For testing, which we will use different image from the training images, using same object proposal extraction method to extract the objects with the help of ground truth and check whether the extracted proposal is car or airplane.
I'm confused about the testing part whether do we need to use ground truth to match with the extracted proposal or not. OR extract any proposal from the image and checked whether its an object or not? How it work?